# Loading external css in Angular 2 and testing it

Tags: testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a component with a test for it. The component has external CSSs that I want to test. I think I am doing everything right, but I couldn't make it to pass the test. Here are my code:
app.component.spec.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { async, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";

describe("App Component", function () {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
        }).compileComponents()
    }));
    it("should instantiate component", () => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof AppComponent).toBe(true);
    });
    it("should have expected <h1> text", () => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        let h1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("h1"));

        expect(h1.nativeElement.innerText).toBe("hello world!");

        expect(h1.nativeElement.style.color).toBe("blue");
    });
});
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "nebula-app",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>hello world!</h1>
```

app.component.css:

```
h1{
    color: blue;
}
```

Only the last expect will fail. It sees h1.nativeElement.style.color as empty. Seems like it didn't load the CSS somehow. If I put the style as in line style in html this test will pass. But having it as an external css will fail the expect.

What am I doing wrong? Is my assumption wrong that the compileComponents should load the external CSS and put it as the style of the nativeElement?

Comment: Colour and background colour are different

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bad in the example. I will edit it, but still does not work

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"does not work"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the last expect will throw an error because it sees h1.nativeElement.style.color as empty. If I put the style as an inline style it will work but having it in an external css file will cause and empty nativelement.style

Comment: An error, or a failed expectation? Could you [edit] with this information?

Comment: failed expectation. Sure I will. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

`h1.nativeElement.style` only contains styles set explicitly on the element. For example, the following element will have a style object with `backgroundColor`set to `red`

```html
<h1 style="background-color: red;">hello world!</h1>
```

Instead of using a unit test for the color, you can test it using protractor e2e tests. There you could write a test like this:

```ts
expect(element(by.css('h1')).getCssValue('color')).toEqual('rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)');
```

Protractor e2e tests are built into Angular2 projects generated by [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). You run them with the command `ng e2e`

Comment: So that's the reason. Yes I changed it to protractor and it worked. But I have a question. Why is that?

Comment: @user3521794 good question. I'm not sure. Maybe they look at it this way: The look and feel of an application belongs not in unit tests but is more naturally a part of integration testing the whole application, where all elements are displayed and affected by all css sheets, including global ones. So that is why they created functionality in e2e to test css.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's a good practice, but it is possible to test the *computed style*.
Changing your last except to something like this should work though:

```
expect(window.getComputedStyle(h1.nativeElement).color).toBe('rgb(0, 0, 255)');
```

Comment: +1 for providing answer that works in scope of component tests.  While it could be argued that these types of checks are better suited in e2e tests.  Sometimes there is great value in simply checking something specific on an individual component without having to spin up whole e2e test.